# How to fire events from Emscripten?

Tags: c++, rxjs, emscripten, rxjs-observables

My project use Angular and RxJS to be reactive, and I'd like to expose some reactive objects from the web-assembly code.
The WASM already uses events (doing internal HTTP requests or managing mouse events), but I have no idea of how to *fire* some events to the JS from the C++, and make the front-end react on them.

So far, our front-end is polling the getters of the wasm to remain up to date, but cannot react to a change.

Comment: Simply call a JS function from WASM? I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @freakish I'm not sure what to put on the JS side, but the goal is to have RxJS Observable object exposing Observable values. So yes, maybe I can trigger a JS function from the C++, a function that would fire the JS event?